# How can a global scope be invalid when creating a route with the "ip" command?

Tags: networking, iproute

I'm trying to create a static NAT, but when I run the command `ip route add nat 172.31.19.02 via 10.0.2.2`, it gives me the error `Error: Invalid scope.`, and it gives the same error when specifying a global scope. I'm trying to replicate what's described on the [Stateless NAT with iproute2](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-stateless.html) page.

My network setup consists of two physical interfaces on the same subnet (ens5, ens6), and one virtual interface for my tinc vpn (vpn). The address 10.0.2.2 is reachable on from the tinc interface. The objective is to forward the traffic from `172.31.19.02` to `10.0.2.2`.

From what I understand from the [IP Address](http://linux-ip.net/html/tools-ip-address.html) page of the documentation, `global` should be "valid everywhere". Is this incorrect?

The relevant section of `ip a`:

```
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [...]
    inet 172.31.19.01/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global ens5
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[...]
3: ens6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether [...]
    inet 172.31.19.02/20 brd 172.31.31.255 scope global ens6
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[...]
4: vpn: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none
    inet 10.0.2.1/24 scope global homeforward
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
[...]
```

My routing tables:

```
$ ip r
default via 172.31.16.1 dev ens5 proto static
10.0.2.0/24 dev homeforward proto kernel scope link src 10.0.2.1
172.31.16.0/20 dev ens6 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.19.02
172.31.16.0/20 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.19.01
$ ip r ls table 1000
default via 172.31.16.1 dev ens5 proto static
172.31.19.01 dev ens5 proto static scope link
$ ip r ls table 1001
default via 172.31.16.1 dev ens6 proto static
172.31.19.02 dev ens6 proto static scope link
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux' route stateless NAT aka "IP NAT dumb" doesn't work (anymore) for a simple reason: the [man page](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-route.8) tells:

> Warning: Route NAT is no longer supported in Linux 2.6.

So examples like [this one](http://linux-ip.net/html/nat-stateless.html#nat-stateless-howto):

> ```
> [root@masq-gw]# ip route add nat 205.254.211.17 via 192.168.100.17
> [root@masq-gw]# ip rule add nat 205.254.211.17 from 192.168.100.17
> [root@masq-gw]# ip route flush cache
> [root@masq-gw]# ip route show table all | grep ^nat
> nat 205.254.211.17 via 192.168.100.17  table local  scope host
> [root@masq-gw]# ip rule show
> 0:      from all lookup local 
> 32765:  from 192.168.100.17 lookup main map-to 205.254.211.17 
> 32766:  from all lookup main 
> 32767:  from all lookup 253
> ```

won't work anymore.

This feature has been added in kernel [2.1.15](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.1/patch-2.1.15.xz) (1996) and [removed in kernel 2.6.9](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v2.6/ChangeLog-2.6.9) (2004) (but probably a few kernels before):

> ```
> <herbert@gondor.apana.org.au>
>   [IPV4]: Kill remnant of ip_nat_dumb
>
>   This line in net/ipv4/Makefile was left behind when the rest of the
>   dumb NAT option was taken out.
>
>   Signed-off-by: Herbert Xu <herbert@gondor.apana.org.au>
>   Signed-off-by: David S. Miller <davem@davemloft.net>
> ```

The [explanation](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/?h=linux-2.6.24.y&id=b4219952356baa162368f2f5dab6421a5dbc5e15) is given in an alternate stateless NAT using [`tc nat`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/tc-nat.8) added back in kernel 2.6.24:

> Previously we had stateless NAT functionality which was integrated
>   into the IPv4 routing subsystem.  This was a great solution as long as
>   the NAT worked on a subnet to subnet basis such that the number of NAT
>   rules was relatively small.  The reason is that for SNAT the routing
>   based system had to perform a linear scan through the rules.
>
> If the number of rules is large then major renovations would have take
>   place in the routing subsystem to make this practical.

---

### tc

Here's a *basic* DNAT example I made. The interface where stateless NAT is performed is `ens5` (I will not use your setup with two NICs in the same LAN: without additional settings, there would be additional problems related to [ARP flux](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-arp.html#ether-arp-flux) and reverse path filtering. It appears you're aware of this since you have additional routing tables, but let's keep this example simple), local addresses on it are 172.31.19.1 and 172.31.19.2. Any *ingress* traffic to 172.31.19.2 is DNATed to destination 10.0.2.2, any *egress* traffic from 10.0.2.2 is SNATed to source 172.31.19.2. As often done, the [*prio* qdisc](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iproute2/tc-prio.8.en.html) is used for its simplicity, not for its priority features.

```
tc qdisc add dev ens5 ingress
tc filter add dev ens5 ingress protocol ip matchall \
   action nat ingress 172.31.19.2/32 10.0.2.2/32

tc qdisc add dev ens5 root handle 1: prio
tc filter add dev ens5 parent 1: protocol ip matchall \
   action nat egress 10.0.2.2/32 172.31.19.2/32
```

There might be unforeseen interactions with netfilter's stateful connection tracking.

---

### nftables

It's also possible instead to do the same using nftables as described in [nftables' wiki](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Performing_Network_Address_Translation_(NAT)#Stateless_NAT).

```
nft add table ip natdumb

nft add chain ip natdumb prerouting '{ type filter hook prerouting priority -350; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip natdumb prerouting ip daddr 172.31.19.2 ip daddr set 10.0.2.2

nft add chain ip natdumb postrouting '{ type filter hook postrouting priority 350; policy accept; }'
nft add rule ip natdumb postrouting ip saddr 10.0.2.2 ip saddr set 172.31.19.2
```

Again, there might be interactions with netfilter's conntrack. I removed any `notrack` which might get it still working if there is no netfilter NAT kernel module loaded or at least activated in the current namespace (while having `notrack` would get all reply packets seen as `NEW` flow rather than `ESTABLISHED`). Feel free to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a route, the kernel checks if it has access to the new scope through a lower scope, because route gateways must be directly reachable on the same L2 (Data Link Layer) connection.

This answer (https://superuser.com/a/1389304) has a good quick clarification of this scope concept and why/when you need to set it up:

> These routes are how you tell the Linux kernel what subnet(s) you're
>   in.
>
> This information isn't stored in a hidden "my current subnet" field
>   when you add an IP address; instead it's always converted to a 'scope
>   link' route with no gateway specified (also called "device route" or
>   "interface route"), and whenever the kernel needs to determine whether
>   some address is directly reachable, it just performs a routing table
>   check.
>
> Normally those routes are added automatically as soon as you configure
>   an IP address – for example, running ip addr add 192.168.1.5/24
>   assigns the IP address 192.168.1.5 and creates a subnet route for
>   192.168.1.0/24. So it's not necessary to add these routes in normal usage.
>
> But when you blindly "delete all routes", you also end up deleting
>   these automatically created routes, and the kernel's "is this address
>   in my subnet" checks no longer work. That's why you end up having to
>   re-add the routes manually.
>
> (The kernel needs to perform this check during ip route add because
>   route gateways (nexthops) must be directly reachable on the same L2
>   connection – they cannot be behind another gateway. That is, the
>   gateway must be in your subnet.
>
> Route scopes are a generic mechanism to express this restriction: the
>   new route's nexthop needs to be reachable through an existing route
>   with a lower scope. In other words, you must go through a local host
>   (link scope) before you can reach a remote host (global scope).)

**EDIT**:

But it was not enough: I've been trying to make it work in a test environment without success so far. `Error: Invalid scope.` keeps happening too.